# How do I center the output of these chunks in R?

Tags: r

[Picture of my assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxiWL.png)

For an assignment, I have to simply show the output of these R chunks. However, it bothers me that it is not centered on the page. I couldn't find anything online about this. Is there a solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by centered on the page?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Beagle! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Your question is highly likely at this point to be ignored, downvoted, and/or closed (needs details). I highly suggest you [edit] your question and add the requested details.

Comment: I think the issue is that your lines are too long, so you get a small right margin.  Try setting `options(width = 60)` (or some other number) to see if it looks better.  This needs to be part of the document you are processing.